Numerical integration using alternatives of Riemann sums
recently I wondered about some details of evaluating integrals of the form $\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{f(x)}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ numerically using Riemann sums. How I understand Riemann sums is that one first partitions the interval $[a,b]$ into sub-intervals $I_{1},I_{2}, ..., I_{N}$ and then approximates $A(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}g(x)$ as a constant within each interval. Finally, the integral is evaluated by summing the areas of all rectangles.
However, are there names for the following alternative operations:

approximate only $A^{\prime}(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}$ as a piecewise-constant function and evaluate afterwards $A^{\prime}(x)g(x)$ using a Riemann sum
approximate only $A^{\prime\prime}(x) = f(x)$ as a piecewise-constant function and evaluate afterwards $A^{\prime\prime}(x)g(x)$ using a Riemann sum

Do you know if one can say anythink general about the alternatives compared to the original idea of Riemann sums? Maybe you even know some paper/literature, where these kind of operations have been discussed?
I am happpy about any help, thank you :)

Are you familiar with the trapezoid rule or Simpson's rule?

As far as I am aware of, the trapezoid rule approximates the function in each interval using trapezoids instead of rectangles and the Simpson rule using a parabola. However, the same set of alternatives I asked  (approximate the whole function vs. approximate only a part of the function) can be applied to these methods, resulting in the same question, doesn't it?

Your option 1 is a (slightly weird) mixture of the Trapezoid rule for $\sqrt{f}$ and the usual Riemann method for $g$.  You might consider using the trapezoidal rule for the whole integrand.

Note that the integrand can change values very quickly near zeroes of $f$ (because the slope of the square root function is vertical at zero).  If $f(c) = 0$, you may be happier to treat this is an improper integral and split the integral at the zeroes of $f$, then split small integrals to the left and right of $c$ where you use $u = (f^{-1}(c-x))^2$ on one side and $u = (f^{-1}(x-c))^2$ on the other side.  This "smooths" the integrands near the singular derivative.

@EricTowers: could you elaborate more, where the trapezoid rule comes into play?
